# Laravel cant access next page because of trying to get property of non object error display error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have given a code that I makes me a bit confused. If I go to my url, it gets me a error of `trying to get property...` and when i use `dd` for the `$response` it says null. Can someone tell me what should I do and why I always get this error? I know this error occur because the `$response` variable does not have and `status` object? Am I right? but when I dd `$response` it says `null`. Thanks in advance

My controller

```
public function pingDomain(Request $request){

        $host = $request->staging == 1 ? env('PROPNEX_IP') : env('PROPNEX_IP_PROD');
        $url = $host. '/propnex/index.php/domain/Ping_domain?domain='.urlencode($request->domain).'&host_ip='.$request->ip;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
            'Content-type: application/json'
        ]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        // dd($response);
      //ERROR IS HERE IN IF STATEMENT
        if ($response->status == 0){

            $host = $request->staging == 1 ? env('PROPNEX_IP') : env('PROPNEX_IP_PROD');
            $url = $host . '/propnex/index.php/pnapi/addDomain?type=own&domain='.$request->domain. '&site-id='. $request->siteid;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
                'Authentication: '.$request->agentid . ':'. $request->auth
            ]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
            curl_close($ch);

            if($response->status == "ok"){
                return redirect()->route('ping-domain-success',[
                    "fname" => $request->fname,
                    "lname" => $request->lname,
                    "agentid" => $request->agenatid,
                    "auth" => $request->auth,
                    "email" => $request->email,
                    "prtname" => $request->prtname,
                    "cea"=> $request->cea,
                    "type" => $request->type,
                    "staging"=> $request->staging,
                    "domain" => $request->domain,
                    'status' => true,
                    "ip" => $request->ip,
                    "siteid"=> $request->siteid,
                    "isRenew" => $request->isRenew
                ]);
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('ping-domain-fail',[
                    "fname" => $request->fname,
                    "lname" => $request->lname,
                    "agentid" => $request->agenatid,
                    "auth" => $request->auth,
                    "email" => $request->email,
                    "prtname" => $request->prtname,
                    "cea"=> $request->cea,
                    "type" => $request->type,
                    "staging"=> $request->staging,
                    "domain" => $request->domain,
                    'status' => true,
                    "ip" => $request->ip,
                    "siteid"=> $request->siteid,
                    "isRenew" => $request->isRenew
                ]);
            }


        }else{
            return redirect()->route('ping-domain-fail',[
                "fname" => $request->fname,
                "lname" => $request->lname,
                "agentid" => $request->agenatid,
                "auth" => $request->auth,
                "email" => $request->email,
                "prtname" => $request->prtname,
                "cea"=> $request->cea,
                "type" => $request->type,
                "staging"=> $request->staging,
                "domain" => $request->domain,
                'status' => true,
                "ip" => $request->ip,
                "siteid"=> $request->siteid,
                "isRenew" => $request->isRenew
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because there's no values in your response and you are trying to access the properties of response, which is not there.

You can put `is_null` check

Put your `if-else` loop in this if condition

```
public function pingDomain(Request $request){

$host = $request->staging == 1 ? env('PROPNEX_IP') : env('PROPNEX_IP_PROD');
$url = $host. '/propnex/index.php/domain/Ping_domain?domain='.urlencode($request->domain).'&host_ip='.$request->ip;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
    'Content-type: application/json'
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
// dd($response);
 //ERROR IS HERE IN IF STATEMENT
if(!is_null($response)){
    if($response->status == 0){

        $host = $request->staging == 1 ? env('PROPNEX_IP') : env('PROPNEX_IP_PROD');
        $url = $host . '/propnex/index.php/pnapi/addDomain?type=own&domain='.$request->domain. '&site-id='. $request->siteid;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
            'Authentication: '.$request->agentid . ':'. $request->auth
        ]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);

        if($response->status == "ok"){
            return redirect()->route('ping-domain-success',[
                "fname" => $request->fname,
                "lname" => $request->lname,
                "agentid" => $request->agenatid,
                "auth" => $request->auth,
                "email" => $request->email,
                "prtname" => $request->prtname,
                "cea"=> $request->cea,
                "type" => $request->type,
                "staging"=> $request->staging,
                "domain" => $request->domain,
                'status' => true,
                "ip" => $request->ip,
                "siteid"=> $request->siteid,
                "isRenew" => $request->isRenew
            ]);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('ping-domain-fail',[
                "fname" => $request->fname,
                "lname" => $request->lname,
                "agentid" => $request->agenatid,
                "auth" => $request->auth,
                "email" => $request->email,
                "prtname" => $request->prtname,
                "cea"=> $request->cea,
                "type" => $request->type,
                "staging"=> $request->staging,
                "domain" => $request->domain,
                'status' => true,
                "ip" => $request->ip,
                "siteid"=> $request->siteid,
                "isRenew" => $request->isRenew
            ]);
        }


    }else{
        return redirect()->route('ping-domain-fail',[
            "fname" => $request->fname,
            "lname" => $request->lname,
            "agentid" => $request->agenatid,
            "auth" => $request->auth,
            "email" => $request->email,
            "prtname" => $request->prtname,
            "cea"=> $request->cea,
            "type" => $request->type,
            "staging"=> $request->staging,
            "domain" => $request->domain,
            'status' => true,
            "ip" => $request->ip,
            "siteid"=> $request->siteid,
            "isRenew" => $request->isRenew
        ]);
    }
}
else{
    // DO what you want here when no data found in response;
}


}
```

Comment: what should i do next about it sir? My other if statement has a `response->status` condition. maybe it should throw an error?

Comment: @user001232 I've updated my answer. Can you please check once. Is it helpful

Comment: undefined variable response sir. how to fix? i didint declare response var in the first place

Comment: @user001232  You are getting this in your blade ?

Comment: `Undefined variable: response` in `C:\Users\Desktop\domain-payment\app\Http\Controllers\DomainOwnController.php`

Comment: `response` is declared after curl here `$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));`

Comment: @user001232 Check my answer once again. I've updated it with whole function this time

Comment: @user001232 Anytime :)

Comment: why does it always go to else statement sir?

Comment: Because you response variable doesn't hold any value

Comment: how can i put some value in my `response->status` variable sir?

Comment: this is not my code anyway. im just fixing it thats why im a bit confused . sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203505/discussion-between-user001232-and-khalid-khan).